# Why doesn't my alphabetical sorting algorithm work?

Tags: python

I made this algorithm in Python to sort a list of names alphabetically and I can't figure out why it doesn't work properly when given [this list](https://projecteuler.net/project/resources/p022_names.txt):

```
for a in range(0,len(V)):
    for b in range(a,len(V)):
        equal=True
        for N in range(0,min(len(V[a]),len(V[b]))):
            if ord(V[b][N])<ord(V[a][N]):
                V[b],V[a]=V[a],V[b]
                equal=False
                break
        if equal==True and len(V[a])>len(V[b]):
            V[b],V[a]=V[a],V[b]
print(V)
```

Comment: Please define *"doesn't work properly"*, and give a [mcve] rather than an off-site link.

Comment: Pair the list down to a handful of names.  Sprinkle in some print statements to see intermediate results.  Also use meaningful names V and N don't really help to understand what you are up to?  Also what's with the ord stuff? python can compare characters directly

Comment: i meant that the list isn't sorted when it gives the result, and sorry for the off-site link but for this list ['h','y','a','q','b','ab','abc'] and it printed the correct output:['a', 'ab', 'abc', 'b', 'h', 'q', 'y'] and when given the huge list off that site it modified the list but it wasn't sorted.

Comment: A= first name which is compared, B= second name which is compared , N= the number for which a pair or letter is compared , and equal is a back up boolean in case the names are of the form JO and JOHN, the last if sequence is mean to replace the longer name with the shorted one if the two are inverted

Comment: also, V is the name of the list which the algorithm is sorting

Comment: Semi off-topic: If you're doing this just to get the problem solved, use `V.sort()`. Otherwise if you're trying to learn about how to sort yourself, I think you should also learn to debug your code as joel proposed above. Apart from that, you should adopt some python ideoms, in particular the [use of whitespace](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#whitespace-in-expressions-and-statements). Also one doesn't `if x == True:` but just `if x:`. Note further that you can compare strings `'bar' < 'foo'` and don't have to iterate over single characters yourself.

Comment: why not try something like >>> str=["MARY","PATRICIA","LINDA","BARBARA","ELIZABETH","JENNIFER","MARIA","SUSAN","MARGARET","DOROTHY","LISA","NANCY"];
>>> str.sort();
>>> print str
['BARBARA', 'DOROTHY', 'ELIZABETH', 'JENNIFER', 'LINDA', 'LISA', 'MARGARET', 'MARIA', 'MARY', 'NANCY', 'PATRICIA', 'SUSAN']

Comment: Tim,I knew those ideoms but i "corrected" the algorithm thinking that maybe it will solve my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, I found the problem. Try dry running your code on these two examples:

```
V = ["ABCZ", "XYZA"]
V = ["ABCE", "XYZF"]
```

For the first example, your if condition isn't triggered until the last characters, 'Z'(from "ABCZ") and 'A'(from "XYZA") are compared.

```
if ord(V[b][N])<ord(V[a][N]):
```

This wrongly swaps the two strings.

Comment: i got it thank you, i think after " if ord(V[b][N])<ord(V[a][N]):" sequence i will add if V[b][N]!=V[a][N]: break

Answer (score 0):

why not try something like putting all strings in a list and then using `sort()`

```
>>> str=["MARY","PATRICIA","LINDA","BARBARA","ELIZABETH","JENNIFER","MARIA","SUSAN",‌​"MARGARET","DOROTHY","LISA","NANCY"];
 >>> str.sort(); 
>>> print str
```

Output:

```
['BARBARA', 'DOROTHY', 'ELIZABETH', 'JENNIFER', 'LINDA', 'LISA', 'MARGARET', 'MARIA', 'MARY', 'NANCY', 'PATRICIA', 'SUSAN']
```

Comment: I tried using str.sort() but like this, print(str.sort()), thinking it will give me a new sorted list instead of modifying the old one, now i know i used that function incorrectly.